# How to finish my DNS setup?

Tags: networking, dns, domain, static-ip

I've been working on a small project the past couple days and have hit a small wall.

This is what I have so far:

1. Static IP from Comcast
2. Registered Domain from Dynadot
3. Local Arch Linux DNS box running named on internal Static IP 10.1.10.205
4. Devices I want on my network point to my Local Arch DNS box for DNS and have their own internal static IPs (So one of my boxes at 10.1.10.206 asks 10.1.10.205 for DNS queries).

What I want is to be able to say "ssh computer1.4lambda.net" and have 4lambda.net resolve to my static IP, which my router forwards the request to be resolved at my local DNS.

Well it isn't working, so I am here!

At Dynadot, I have my domain DNS record updated with:

```
4lambda.net        A        50.249.112.214
```

Is that correct? This should be routing any queries to example.com to 50.249.112.214 which will lead that query to my Comcast modem/router.

From there, do I need to do anything such as forward port 53 to my local DNS or do I just tell my router to use my local DNS?

I am sure my local one is working, when I run "ssh computer1.example.com" internally it does find the other computer and resolve. Removing computer1 from my local DNS causes it to fail, so I am under the assumption that at least that is correct. I still don't understand why I can't do "ssh computer1" from a local machine though. However that is not as important.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: `For security reasons I am using example.com` - See here for what information to obfuscate in your answer. If this is a publicly registered domain name then what's the point of obfuscating the name? That's just making it harder for us to help you. - http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts

Comment: Point taken. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to port forward your ports like 80 in your router. Also, what's your TTL? How long ago was it when you changed your DNS records? When your TTL is set to 24 hours (which is standard), it can take up to 24 hours before your DNS records are active.

For clarification: the TTL is the value of the time before previous records are deleted. So for example, if you change your DNS records and your TTL is set to five minutes, your records should be updated in five minutes. After updating your TTL and saving your DNS records, change your TTL to a larger value than twelve hours, it's not recommended (your nameservers may exclude you) your TTL is less than twelve hours for a long time. Ideally, your TTL is always 24 hours.

Comment: I have to check when I get home but I thought I had made it 24. Wouldn't I only forward 80 if I was hosting a web page?

Comment: @Russell If your web server runs on the port 80, you'd have to port forward port 80. If you only use your server for another purpose (e.g. a game server running on port 25565) you'd have to port forward 25565 :)

Comment: Thanks, so if I was using it for DNS id have to forward port 53?

Comment: If your DNS server is bound to port 53, yes :)

Comment: I was thinking more that since a DNS request should auto forward to port 53 that I should forward that to my DNS box to resolve names like "computer1.4lambda.net." I'll try it tonight and report back! Thanks, I think I am fairly close!